# Graph isometry versus graph isomorphism

Tags: graph-theory

I am reading this page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_cube

They say that a partial cube is a graph that is isometric to a subgraph of a hypercube. I know that isometric in this context means that there exists a mapping between the vertex sets that preserves the graph distance. Is this equivalent to saying that a partial cube is a graph that isomorphic to a subgraph of a hypercube - or is there some detail I am missing?

Comment: Isometric is a little stronger, it is a subgraph with the distances preserved (ie when you consider the partial cube as a subgraph of the cube, the distances in between vertices the partial cube graph are the same as the distances in the cube graph)

Comment: Is there a simple example of an injective edge-preserving map between graphs that doesn't preserve the graph distance? I can't really see how there could be one.

Comment: @MorganRodgers I think I have an example. Let $\{0,1\}^3$ be the set of all bit strings of length three. Let $Q_3$ be the hypercube graph - i.e. connect two 3-bit strings iff they differ by a single digit. Then the graph $G = (V,E)$ with vertices $V = \{000,010,011,001\}$ and edges $ E = \{\{000,010\},\{010,011\},\{011,001\}\}$ is isomorphic to a subgraph of the $Q_3$ but is not isometric to a a subgraph of the hypercube since $d_g(000,001) = 3$ but $d_{Q_3}(000,001) = 1$. Is this a correct counter-example?

Comment: You can also just look at a 4-cycle mapped to the vertices of $K_{4}$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Got it. Thanks!